# .Net Core Nullable - confusing errors regarding

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nullreferenceexception, nullable-reference-types

I have a .Net Core 3.1 ASP.NET application, in which I've enabled nullables:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

It also uses `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` (3.3.0), as well as `StyleCop.Analyzers`.

I have a method with the following signature:

```
 public async Task<SomeResponse> DoSomethingAsync(IIdentity identity)
```

In that method, I have the following:

```
string? adfsUpn = identity.Name;
```

But, this gives me the warning:

> Error CA1062  In externally visible method [...], validate parameter
> 'identity' is non-null before using it. If appropriate, throw an
> ArgumentNullException when the argument is null or add a Code Contract
> precondition asserting non-null argument.

Basically, it's stating that I shouldn't access the `.Name` property on the `identity`object unless I've tested it for null first.

However....

When I call this method (from the Controller) I pass in `this.User.Identity` and intellisense shows me that both `this.User` and `this.User.Identity` are not null.

Back to my method...I add the following guard clause at the top:

```
if (identity == null)
{
    .....
}
```

But now I'm told that identity can never be null and that `identity == null` will always be false.  That's what I'm hoping for with the use of "Nullable", but it seems that Visual Studio or FxCop or StyleCop hasn't interpreted the situation correctly.

I'm likely just to add a pragma statement to ignore this, but before I do, just wanted to check that I wasn't missing something....

Comment: You can use null-forgiving operator `!` to tell that `identity` can't be null, like `identity!.Name`

Comment: If the error is thrown by analyzer, you may check its rules for support the latest language features

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is currently a known [false positive](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2875).  Also looks like it's [on their radar](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2877) but there hasn't been any movement on it in a while.

I'd personally probably just suppress that warning, in this particular case.